# how to plot 2 histograms side by side?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have 2 dataframes.  I want to plot a histogram based on a column 'rate' for each, side by side.  How to do it?

I tried this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.subplot(1,2,1)

dflux.hist('rate' , bins=100) 
plt.subplot(1,2,2) 
dflux2.hist('rate' , bins=100) 
plt.tight_layout() 
plt.show()
```

It did not have the desired effect.  It showed two blank charts then one populated chart.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [**`subplots`**](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to define a figure with two axes.  Then specify the axis to plot to within `hist` using the `ax` parameter.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

dflux.hist('rate', bins=100, ax=axes[0])
dflux2.hist('rate', bins=100, ax=axes[1])
```

**Demo**

```
dflux = pd.DataFrame(dict(rate=np.random.randn(10000)))
dflux2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(rate=np.random.randn(10000)))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)

dflux.hist('rate', bins=100, ax=axes[0])
dflux2.hist('rate', bins=100, ax=axes[1])
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!  I also found to set a title on each I do:  `axes[0].set_title('left title')` and then `axes[1].set_title('right title')`

Comment: @MarkGinsburg you can also set the title with the title parameter in the call to hist

Comment: i tried this `dflux2.hist('rate' , bins=100, ax=axes[1], title='king') `  but syntax error, it says `Unknown Property title`

Comment: @MarkGinsburg hmm guess I was wrong (-:  good thing you figured it out

Comment: @piRSquared, you are the Putnam Exam Master!:) Question, what if I am doing this to 2 or 3 scatterplots, how do I make them be next to each other? This is the code I currently have for one:  **bold [fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2)

plt.xlim(0,2000000)
plt.ylim(0,250000)
ax.scatter(Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Revenues[Booked], Sales_Force_Before_Merger.Amount[Booked], alpha=0.05, color='g')
ax.set_title("Revenue vs Amount for Booked Before Merger")
ax.set_xlabel("Revenue", size = 10)
ax.set_ylabel("Amount", size = 10)
ax.plt.xticks(fontsize=10)
ax.plt.show(ax=axes[0])] **

Comment: @mkheifetz I recommend you ask a new question.  It's difficult to parse what you've posted.  Not only will asking a new question give you the opportunity to state your question clearly, it also gives would be answerers an opportunity to earn reputation in answering.

Comment: Is is possible to do this for a line chart

Comment: I've got this code: def plot_it(Product):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    plt.plot(df_price[Product],'r-o',label='Price')
    plt.plot(df_rsp[Product],'b-o',label='RSP')
    plt.plot(df_promo[Product],'y-o',label='Promo')
    plt.plot(df_povrsp[Product],'g-o',label='PovRSP')
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches((18, 5))
    plt.legend().set_visible(True)
    plt.tight_layout()

Comment: For matplotlib version 3.7.2, this works for Pandas dataframes, but does not work when I use the matplotlib.pyplot plt.hist.